# React and the pattern MVVM

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, mvvm

I have been reading a lot about MVC and MVVM. These are not new concepts to me, but I'm starting to question about some of the facts of each one, more precisely, what is the view model in the context of the MVVM pattern. In the context of MVC it is pretty straighforward: a simple class that may aggregate data from multiple entities. This entities can also be called models in the context of MVC, but the model term has a broader definition, that extends to the business logic, processing of the data and, of course, includes the models (or database table -entities). In the MVVM, the model has the same definition, and the View definition is the same for both patterns (in a nutshell, what the user sees). The question arises with the ViewModel in the context of MVVM. What exactly is the ViewModel in the MVVM pattern? In react, by having a component that can have state and data, can it be considered a ViewModel? I have also read that the ViewModel relies in two-way data binding...which goes against react (since it uses one-way databinding). Can someone clearly explain the pattern MVVM, more precisely, the ViewModel keyword? Or give an example in the context of React? Thank you in advance.